# Save other data from ajax post to cakephp controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I hava a data from a table and i want to POST and receive the data on my function of my controller, that is fine, now If I try to save the data it give me a error:

js:

```
        $('#bot_guar').click( function () {
        //var rows = $("#tabla1").dataTable().fnGetNodes(); 

        var oTable = $('#tabla1').dataTable();
        var dat = oTable.fnGetData();
        var t=dat;
        //alert(t[0][0]);
        $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "<?= Router::Url(['controller' => 'cab_facturas', 'action' => 'addDetFac'], TRUE); ?>/",//teacher//getdata/3
        data:{value_to_send:JSON.stringify(t)}, 
        success: function(data){    
            alert(data+'the data was successfully sent to the server');
        }//success
        });     

    });
```

Controller;

```
class CabFacturasController extends AppController {
var $uses = array('CabFactura', 'DetFactura','Dosificacion','Articulo');
public $helpers = array('Html','Form','Js'=>array('Jquery'));
    public function addDetFac() {

       $this->autoRender = false;
       if( $this->request->is('post')) {
         // echo $_POST['value_to_send'];
        $array=json_decode($_POST['value_to_send']);
        $data = array(
            'DetFactura' => array(
                'cab_factura_id' => $array[0][0],
                'cab_factura_id_agencia' => $array[0][1],
                'articulo_id' => $array[0][2],
                'cantidad' => $array[0][4],
                'precio' => $array[0][5],
                'monto' => $array[0][6],
                'nro_lote' => $array[0][7],
            )
        );
        $this->DetFactura->create();
        $this->DetFactura->save($data);
        echo $data['DetFactura']['cab_factura_id'];
        //die();
        }
}
```

}

the message error:
POST http://localhost/cake/facturacion/cab_facturas/addDetFac/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

At this moment I can show my data that is send, but when I add that I cant. PLEASE help me.

Comment: `500 (Internal Server Error)` means: go and read your error logs.

Comment: I was unable to found error log, I found it: xampp\htdocs\cake\facturacion\tmp\logs was a insert constraint error. :/ thank you very much!!!. By the way all my code its ok. =)